# SQL Server record being created twice in Entity Framework 6 when it should only create one

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to track down a bug in the following code.

If a record does not exist with today's date, then create one.

For some reason intermittently a record is being created twice with the same datetime stamp. This method is only called once in the app.

Any ideas on how I can stop this?

```
if (!_context.Widgets.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.WidgetDate) == DateTime.Today.Date))
{
    return CreateWidgets(DateTime.Today);
}

return _context.Widgets.First(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.WidgetDate) == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

Comment: Is there more than one person using that app at the same time?

Comment: Can easily be caused by concurrency. The final guard should always be a unique index in the database.

Comment: Yes there will be more than one person viewing at the same time.   The strange thing is that the duplicate records both have identical timestamps and it is the same username who is logged in to the app.

Comment: What happens in `CreateWidgets`? And where/when do you create `_context`?

Comment: HI I am using Ninject to create context and createWidgets just inserts a record with datetimestamp.